# Gmail API OAUTH in google COLAB

Tags: google-api, google-colaboratory

There are numerous posts on this question, but fundamentally, the problem is that there is no way to complete the oauth process.

You need to have a listener, that can pick up the authentication success, but colab might be able to listen to localhost, but when you are running this in colab, and approve the OAUTH, it's your LOCAL browser that is trying to interpret localhost, and it fails.

IE

```
 flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(/content/drive/MyDrive/cred.json', SCOPES) 
 creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
```

The only way I can see to fix this is to use some janky form of ngrok to tunnel and replace localhost with the ngrok address.

Another janky solution is to use a local jupyter notebook, grab the token and then copy it to your colab.

But both of these fail the sniff test of being able to pass this code to someone else to run in colab.

Can someone at Google Colab please fix this please.